# 404 Response not being set on error | Node.JS & MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm facing a issue in a Node.JS application I'm writing.
I'm trying to get a JSON string as POST and saving that JSON to mongodb.

Inserts are working fine but I'm not able to handle error scenarios from snippet which is responsible for interacting with mongodb.

E.g. in the snippet below, I'm getting expected 404 response at "Error" comments #1, 3, 4 in server.js, when respective conditions are fulfilled, but 404 response at comment #2 is not coming.

However, I am getting errors printed in console from **insertintomongo.js** at comment #5 and 6 and that error object is also successfully sent back to server.js.

I'm not able to figure out why response is not set to 404 even when I know that code has gone into correct *if* condition (as shown by console output).

Snippet of JS handling requests (**server.js**)

```
var imongo=require("./insertintomongo.js");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
 if (uri == "/ssd/add" && request.method == 'POST') {
    console.log(request.method + " to " + request.url);
    var fullBody = '';

    request.on('data', function(chunk) {
      fullBody += chunk.toString();
    });

    request.on('end', function() {
      try {
        JSON.parse(fullBody);
      } catch (e) {
        // Error 1  
        console.log('Invalid JSON. Error message: ' +e);
        response.writeHead(404, "Input data is not in JSON format" , {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.end('<html><head><title>Input data is not in JSON format</title></head><body><h1>Input data is not in JSON format</h1></body></html>');
      }
      var inputJSON = JSON.parse(fullBody);
      if ( inputJSON.deployment_id != undefined ){
        inputJSON._id=inputJSON.deployment_id;
        imongo(inputJSON,function(err){
          if(err){
            // Error 2
            console.log('Error 2: ' + err);
            response.writeHead(404, "Error saving input data" , {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            response.end('Error inside callback');
          } else {
            console.log("All good");
          };
        });
      } else {
        // Error 3
        console.log("Incorrect json provided");
        response.writeHead(404, "Incorrect json provided", {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.end('<html><head><title>Incorrect json provided</title></head><body><h1>Incorrect json provided.</h1><h3>"deployment_id" field is missing.</h3></body></html>');
      };

      // OK 1
      response.writeHead(200, "OK", {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      response.end();
    });
 } else {
    // Error 4
    response.writeHead(405, "Method not supported", {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.end('<html><head><title>Method not supported</title></head><body><h1>Method not supported.</h1></body></html>');
  }
}).listen(8081);
```

**insertintomongo.js** which is included in above JS

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mytest';
function saveToMongo(input,cb){
  MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
      // Error 5
      console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
      cb(err);
    } else {
      var collection = db.collection('users');

      collection.insert([input], function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          // Error 6
          cb(err);
        } else {
          console.log('Inserted '+ result.result.ok+ ' documents into collection. The documents inserted with "_id" are:' + JSON.stringify(result.ops));
          cb(null);
        }
      db.close();
    });
  }
  });
};

module.exports=saveToMongo;
```

Here's Console output

```
Server runing at 8081
POST to /ssd/add
// This is coming from inserttomongo.js
Error 5: Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error: { [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27018]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27018' }
// This is coming from server.js
Error 2: MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27018
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, figured out the issue. I had to remove these lines from previous place and put it in else condition of "Error 2" comment.

```
  // OK 1
  response.writeHead(200, "OK", {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  response.end();
```

This is because call to *imongo* is async and response was being set 200 even before the *imongo* was finished.

Very basic mistake :(